# Difference between *str and atoi(str)

Tags: c, tokenize, strtok

I was tokenizing, and used strtok on a text file (which has been read into an array 'store') with the delimiter '='

so there was a statement in the file : `TCP.port = 180`

And I did:

```
str = strtok(store, "=");

str= strtok(NULL, "=");
```

Now if I do `*str`, it gives me '82' (probably some junk value)
but `atoi(str);` gives me 180 (the correct value)

I was hoping someone could shed light onto this, shouldn't dereferencing str give me 180 too?

Comment: You should not use strtok. Use strtok_r for thread safety.

Comment: can you please paste the whole piece of code where that is happening?

Comment: 82 is the ASCII representation of the character `'R'`. Are you sure that's what you got? If `atoi(str)` gave you 180, `*str` should probably have given you 49, the ASCII representation of `'1'`.

Comment: Keith thanks for bringin that to light..I was indeed getting 49

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile and run this program.  It should give you a better idea of what's going on.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *s = "180";
    printf("s       = \"%s\"\n", s);
    printf("atoi(s) = %d\n", atoi(s));
    printf("*s      = %d = '%c'\n", *s, *s);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
s       = "180"
atoi(s) = 180
*s      = 49 = '1'
```

Comment: Alright got it.
Do u mind telling me what const char *s = "180"; means? are we making s point to the memory location #180 or something else?

Comment: @Siddhartha: No, it's nothing like that at all.  `"180"` is a string literal, specifying an array of characters with the values `{ '1', '8', '0', '\0' }` (that last `'\0'` is a null character, indicating the end of the string).  `s` is a pointer, which is initialized to point to the beginning of that string.  You can see that the first `printf` call prints the string "180".

Comment: Thanks a ton. Extremely helpful.

I think if we said const char *s = 180 (or a valid memory location) that would've meant location #180 (though most probably it wud give a compiler mismatch error)

Comment: @Siddhartha: The correct way to do that would be `const char *s = (const char*)180;` -- though it's very unlikely that that would be a good idea.  There's no implicit conversion from int to any pointer type (apart from the special case of 0, which is a null pointer constant).

Answer (score 2):

No. `atoi` gives you the integer represented by the string `str` points to. Dereferencing `str` (*str) gives you the value of the char `str` points to (which is not the value you wrote).

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand exactly how strings work in C to see what's going on here.  The `str` variable is a pointer to the first character in the string.  Dereferencing `str` gives the value pointed to by `str`, namely the character `'1'`.  Similarly, dereferencing `str+1` will give you the next character, `'8'`.  You can see how the end of the string is signified with `*(str+3)` (or, equivalently, `str[3]`), which gives a null byte.  The function `atoi` knows how to interpret the characters as a base-10 string of ASCII characters, which is much more complicated than a dereference.

Comment: Thanks a lot that clears up..I would have voted u up had I the reputation :D